# Authorizing my app script library for personal use

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I have developed a Script App that works with forms. It's perform tasks like:

1. sending emails
2. read/write data to a spreadsheet
3. read/write document properties to PropertiesService

> But, I'm stuck with a warning that says "authorization is required to perform that action".

I assume by "that action" is referring to accessing to PropertiesService, because it is what that library's function does.

I have been trying to understand google articles like this one: https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/getting-started#enable_an_api

and this one:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects.

But frankly, I don't understand what I can do to authorize my library script to be used in my forms or maybe for other Google users that want to use it in their own forms.

I intend to make it private if it is possible.

Plus, I have searched in Google Cloud Console trying to create a project. That's the furthest I've come because I don't know how can I relate my script to that project.

What I'm missing?

**Edit:** Thanks @Cooper for your corrections to my post. I really appreciate it and It's very useful as I improve little by little my writing skills. I've noticed that I may mixed up the terms "editor add-on", "library" and "standalone script". Right know, I understand this: The first two are, at the end, standalone scripts. The difference I see is that the first one requiere to have special registering and the script has to have some special functions to do the signing. The second one, honesty, I don't see the difference. I included a standalone script deployed as a Library in my Bounded script and I can call a library function from the html form (generated by the same library) without using the namespace name.

**Edit 2:**

This is the message showed when I visited the URL to authorize the script that include the Library (I guess that Library is the one that need authorization due to it is the one performing actions).

[image]

the scripts parts are the following:

In the Form's bounded script:

```
function onOpen() {
  CDOLib.setProps(PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperties());
  CDOLib.initCDOLib();
}
```

In the CDOLib:

```
 function initCDOLib() {
      var authInfo = ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL)
      if (authInfo.getAuthorizationStatus() ==
          ScriptApp.AuthorizationStatus.REQUIRED) {
        showReauthorizationRequest();          
    }
drawMenu_();
    }
    function showReauthorizationRequest() {
      var settings = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
      var authInfo = ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL);
    
    Logger.log("URL AUTH: " + authInfo.getAuthorizationUrl());
    }
    
    function drawMenu_() {
      var menu = FormApp.getUi().createMenu("CDO engine");
    
      var endDate = props.getProperty("CDO_END_DATE");
      if (endDate) {
        menu.addItem("Print CDO", "CDOLib.print")
          .addSeparator()
          .addItem("End CDO", "CDOLib.endCDO");
      }
      else {
        menu.addItem('Start CDO', 'CDOLib.initializeCDO');
      }
    
      menu.addToUi();
    }
```

**Edit 3:**

content of appscript.json file:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": []
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Comment: At what point to you get the ` "authorization is required to perform that action".` message? Can you post a screenshot of this?

Comment: I think that is getUi.ShowModalWindow() method. The error message is that I don't have authorization to show windows. I edited the script and add a routine to get auth info and show it send the URL authorization, if it is the case. Same thing. Also, the URL give me error when I go there. I know that I must doing something stupid in that point, but I can't see it yet and I didn't found a proper tutorial for people apparently dump like me

Comment: Also, I want to know if there is a way to authorize a library so I don't have to authorize in every new form I include it

Comment: From what context do you get the authentication required message? Are you running the function from the script editor, or custom function?

Comment: I was running the script from the Form (whose script include the library with code that trigger the error message) from a menu item in it and I got an error message, but it wasn't clear about the reazon of failure. When I ran the problematic function directly from the library on app script console (like a standalone script, right?), the message was the one I showed here

Comment: Can you provide the script you're trying to run from the menu bar?

Comment: Hi Rafa. I edited the post to include the message showeb when I try to authrize the script visiting the URL I get with ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL).getAuthorizationUrl() method.

Comment: I also added the script part that gives me an error.
I think the main problem is that it never ask the user for authorization with a visible notification, like in the document bounded scripts.

Comment: in Log, you can see the following:
Exception: You do not have permission to call Ui.showDialog. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui

Comment: Can you share your appsscript.json file? Sounds like it's a missing scopes issue

Comment: I edited the post adding the appscript.json file content.
I though that the scopes would automatically add to appscrip.json when you had mention them in the script. So ¿Do you think that is it?

Comment: Hi, are you still having a problem? If that's the case, can you (1) provide the code related to `setProps` and (2) are you running this via add-on?

Comment: Hi @lamblichus. `setPtops` just get a copy of `PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()` in Form. Doing this, I'm able to read/write properties for that particular Form.

Comment: About running as an add-on, the answer is no. I was just deploying as Library. I guesses that was the way for libraries. Are you suggesting I to test with deploy as add-on?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour. I'm not getting any error when I click `CDO engine` from the custom menu. Can you provide a clear set of reproduction steps in order to troubleshoot this? (btw I mentioned the add-on because they require setting explicit scopes, and since you are getting an error related to scopes I thought that might be the case - see [setting explicit scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes)).

Comment: Actually, the reason for this issue most probably is that you are trying to access a service that requires authorization with a simple `onOpen` trigger, and simple triggers cannot access services that require authorization. The solution in this case would be to have an [installed](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `onOpen` trigger instead. Do you think that would be appropriate for your situation?

Comment: You're right. Could be an option to have an installed trigger. Anyway, I don't know how to do it in a context of a library. I will investigate some little more about it and I'll tell you. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You would install it in the main script, so it would be like installing it in a normal context. If you need help doing that, I'd consider posting an answer explaining this.